# read a file from my vm, angular js

Tags: angularjs, virtual-machine, readfile

I am a new developer and have the task of reading the version of our app from a file. it is dynamically generated and is located in my VM.  to access the directory where it is located, I do ssh vm_name, sudo su -, cd name/of/directory.  is it possible to write a function in the main controller that can read from this file via a normal $http get request?

I tried this:

```
$http.get('name/of/directory/filename.text').success(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

result:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/name/of/directory/filename.txt 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: If there are no security restrictions (such as CORS, for example), it should be straight forward. What have you tried so far? Can you share some code?

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. It's not working because the file is not found so make sure the file is in the specified location. Are you referencing the file correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure how to reference a file that is in my vm